# Xilinx PLanAhead crashing

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I have installed xilinx ISE 10.1, 13.2 and 14.7.My code synthesizes but PlanAhead not opening on windows 10 64-bit.I googled and find a solution of replacing rdiArgs.bat file present in bin folder.I did that but still unable to launch Xilinx PlanAhead.Kindly suggest me the possible way to overcome this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PlanAhead will not open when you are running 64-bit Project Navigator (e.g. for I/O Pin Planning), it just displays the splash screen but never opens.

To fix it, we have to force PlanAhead to always run in 32-bit mode.

Open C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\PlanAhead\bin and rename rdiArgs.bat to rdiArgs.bat.orig

Download the zip file from here:

https://www.eevblog.com/forum/fpga/guide-getting-xilinx-ise-to-work-with-windows-8-64-bit/?action=dlattach;attach=102040

Extract it. You should now have a file named rdiArgs.bat
Copy the new rdiArgs.bat file to C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\PlanAhead\bin

DONE!